# Упрощенное/приближённое представление чисел с плавающей точкой как дробей в SymPy

Tags: python, sympy

Как представить в `8/9 * x` или `8 * x/9` с помощью методов sympy след. выражение? Как показывает пайтон так точнее и самому приятнее смотреть :)

```
0.888888888888889 * x
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import sympy
x = sympy.Symbol('x')
print(sympy.nsimplify(0.888888888888889 * x))
```

Вывод: `8*x/9`

http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/modules/simplify/simplify.html#nsimplify

Comment: Отлично, спасибо вам!

Answer (score 3):

Вариант без sympy:

```
from fractions import Fraction

x = 1000  # лимит точности
print(Fraction(1.0616666666666668).limit_denominator(x))

>>> 637/600  # если x == ∞
>>> 396/373  # если x == 400
>>> 241/227  # если x == 300
```

В sympy точность измеряется в параметре tolerance `nsimplify(pi, tolerance=0.01)`